# rxjava - how to add Timer to observerable after creation

Tags: timer, rx-java

I would like to catch an observable thats loading an add and have it show after a few seconds.  Im calling this is multiple places but in one particular place i'd like it to only run after a few seconds have elapsed.  Here is the method i have that returns an observable:

```
private Observable fullScreenAdObservable(){


    // Create the interstitial.
 return  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
     @Override
     public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(main.this);
         interstitial.setAdUnitId(admob_publisherID);
         // Create ad request.
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
         // Begin loading your interstitial.
         interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
         interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
             @Override
             public void onAdLoaded() {
                 super.onAdLoaded();
                 interstitial.show();
             }
         });
     }
     });
 }
```

then to subscribe i do this but the timer one fails:

```
 fullScreenAdObservable().subscribe();//this works
fullScreenAdObservable().timer(0,3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(); //this fails to react,why ?
```

I want the timer to run the observerable after 3 seconds but it wont, why ?

Comment: Have you checked `delay` operator? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html

Comment: timer() is a static method on Observable, not an instance method so it won't subscribe to your fullScreenAdObservable.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some scheduling issue when using delay and timer.  So i had to explicity tell what thread i want to subscribe on BEFORE calling the delaySubscription or timer. Also modified the subscriber to listen for onNext so i can pass the subscriber a ad. Then i actually showed the ad in the onNext (as its triggered after the delay is elapsed.

```
private Observable fullScreenAdObservable(){

    // Create the interstitial.
 return  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
     @Override
     public void call(final Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(main.this);
         interstitial.setAdUnitId(admob_publisherID);
         // Create ad request.
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
         // Begin loading your interstitial.
         interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
         interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
             @Override
             public void onAdLoaded() {
                 super.onAdLoaded();
                 //emit a loaded ad
                 subscriber.onNext(interstitial);                     
             }
         });
     }
 });
 }
```

//and to call it :

```
 fullScreenAdObservable().subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            delaySubscription(13, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(new Action1<InterstitialAd>() {
        @Override
        public void call(InterstitialAd ad) {
            ad.show();
        }
    });
```